# How to join the same table more than once to select different columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find out users who have either made or received a booking.

I have two tables that look like this:

Users:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
+----+
```

Bookings:

```
+----+-----+-----+
| id | rid | oid |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | 1   | 2   |
| 2  | 2   | 1   |
| 3  | 3   | 4   |
+----+-----+-----+
```

A booking has two users, a 'rider' (rid), and an 'owner' (oid).

The rider and owner can't be the same for each booking but riders can also be owners.

My output should be a list of user IDs that correspond with users who have made or received a booking.

So far I have written

```
select u.id, b1.rid, b2.oid
from users u
left join bookings b1
on u.id = b1.rid
left join bookings b2
on u.id = b2.oid;
```

And various other permutations, but I'm not getting the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And how is the time window defined?

Comment: @amaitu you don't need to join or even use the users table. You only need bookings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all User IDs that are either in Bookings.rid or Bookdings.oid. So you could do something like:

```
select
  users.id
from
  users
where
  users.id in (select bookings.rid from bookings)
  or
  users.id in (select bookings.oid from bookings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize a `UNION` clause here. 
However, you don't define what the "time window" is, so I am not sure we can come up with a complete solution for you. However, try something like the following:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    bookings.rid,
    bookings.oid
FROM
    users
        LEFT JOIN bookings ON users.id = bookings.rid

UNION ALL

SELECT
    users.id,
    bookings.rid,
    bookings.oid
FROM
    users
        LEFT JOIN bookings ON users.id = bookings.oid
```

Answer (score 0):

> My output should be a list of user IDs that correspond with users who have made or received a booking.

To do that, you only need to look at the `bookings` table :

```
SELECT DISTINCT rid id FROM bookings
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT oid FROM bookings
```

The `DISTINCT` removes the duplicates returned by each query, and the `UNION ALL` removes duplicates across both queries.

If you are looking to filter by time frame :

```
SELECT DISTINCT rid id FROM bookings WHERE some_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT oid FROM bookings WHERE some_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
```

Where `some_date` is the field that contains the booking date, and `:start_date`/`end_date` are the beginning and the end of the date interval.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a `name` column in `Users` table. 
If you want this too then:

```
select users.id, users.name from (
  select rid userid from bookings
  union
  select oid userid from bookings
) t inner join users
on users.id = t.userid
group by users.id, users.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7r8mY8A7Z33jGtiuZHF79/0)
If not you only need to scan the `bookings` table:

```
select distinct userid from (
  select rid userid from bookings
  union
  select oid userid from bookings
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7r8mY8A7Z33jGtiuZHF79/1)